# Showing all choice option at once in one Sonata Admin Form's Select

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony4

Inside $formMapper variable in sonata's src/Admin/TareaspendientesAdmin.php file I have:

```
->add('subcategoria', ChoiceType::class, [
        'placeholder' => 'Select Subcategory',
        'choices'  => [
        // Categoría: Coche
        'Recambios' => '21',
        'ITV' => '22',

        // Categoría: Compras
        'Alimentacion' => '91',
        'Limpieza' => '92',
        'LeroyMerlin-Bricodepo' => '93',
        'Libros-Cultura' => '94',
        'Otros-compras' => '95',

        // Categoría: Doméstica
        'Limpieza-casa' => '11',
        'Ordenar-casa' => '12',

        // Categoría: Eguzkilore
        'Instalaciones' => '51',
        'Hacienda' => '52',
        'Facturas' => '53',
        'Otros-eguzkilore' => '54',

        // Categoría: Viajes
        'Mapas-GPS' => '61',
        'Alojamiento' => '62',
        'Vuelos' => '63',
        'Otros-viajes' => '64',

        ],
```

In the html file that originates, when you select 'Select Subcategory' the options are displayed, but it only show us the first 6, and you must use the scroll to see the others.

Question: How can I show all of them at once (suppose they are 11) without using the scroll?

I have tried the following. I have located the file that draws the form:

```
vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/Form/form_admin_fields.html.twig
```

I add size="11" in the next row:

```
<select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %} size="11">
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution: I found it in the following css file:

```
public/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2.css
```

you have to modify the max-height property (set by default to 200px) in the class .select2-results:

```
.select2-results {
    max-height: 800px;
```